# Mobile jquery page is loading continuously, if i put custom parameter in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My below site is properly working without having any parameter in URL.
But if i add any parameter manually in URL then click on "Hotels" & "Trip Planner" then page is OK. but if i go for "Car Search" tab then page is not properly working.
I hope its because of Tabs are there.

**Working**
http://technosphereindia.com/mydesign/mobile3/index.html#car_page

**Not Working** http://technosphereindia.com/mydesign/mobile3/index.html?abc=12#car_page

I am new for mobile jquery and don't have deep knowledge of mobile jquery. can someone please help me rectify this issue ?

Comment: try doing your custom request at the end of the url -- http://technosphereindia.com/mydesign/mobile3/index.html#car_page?abc=12

Comment: Thanks Tasos, but if i put this parameter very first time, when open the root level of site, http://technosphereindia.com/mydesign/mobile3/index.html?abc=12 . it does not automatically set like "#car_page?abc=12".

Answer (score 0):

you are using the parameters in the wrong order.

- First you have to set the # (hash part of the query string)
- The parameters query will need to follow the hash

Here is how it should be:

> http://technosphereindia.com/mydesign/mobile3/index.html#car_page?abc=12